# Nowhere dense set $P_{\alpha} \subset [0;1]$

Tags: measure-theory

Is it possible to construct a closed nowhere dense set without isolated points $P_{\alpha} \subset [0;1]$ such that its Lebesgue measure would be equal to any value $0 \le \alpha \le 1$ ?

Case $\alpha = 1$ looks extremely questionable. Case $\alpha = 0$ is a [Cantor set](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CantorSet.html).

P.S. Is there an English word for a closed set without isolated points?

Comment: Perfect set, to your P.S.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Does that definition take care of isolated points as well?

Comment: Perfect = closed and without isolated points.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes for all but $\alpha=1$. The construction is exactly the same as the Cantor set, only instead of removing intervals whose measures sum up to $1$, you remove intervals whose measures sum up to $1-\alpha$.

These sets are called ["Fat Cantor sets"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) or "Generalized Cantor sets".

Answer (score 3):

A set in $[0,1]$ that has measure $1$ is dense.  But if it is also nowhere dense...

Comment: Very neat property. What is the nature of its proof? How far can it be generalized? I even posted a new question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357119