# Regarding nowhere dense subsets and their measure.

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces

A while ago it was made clear that a nowhere dense subset $P \subset [0;1]$ whose Lebesgue measure $\mu(P) = \mu([0;1]) = 1$ [doesn't exist](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/329780).

But is it possible in principle to define a nowhere dense subset $P \subset X$ so that its Lebesgue measure $\mu(P) = \mu(X) < \infty$ for some metric space? Or does it hold a contradiction somewhere?

I was wondering maybe $\mu(P) = \mu(X)$ implies that $P$ is dense everywhere (hence cannot be nowhere dense at the same time) but I am not confident about this at all.

Comment: I am confused by the phrase "for some metric space". The Lebesgue measure is a construction specifically for $\mathbb{R}^n$. Are you interested in a more general setting?

Comment: @SeanGomes Sorry for confusion. I'd be wholeheartedly satisfied with $\mathbb{R}^n$ case. Yet the metric can be any function satisfying the definition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition

Comment: Whether a set is nowhere dense in $\Bbb R^n$ is a topological question: it does not depend on the specific metric chosen, so long as that metric generates the usual topology. And if it does not, then you’re no longer dealing with $\Bbb R^n$ and Lebesgue measure.